# fetching data from appropriate table according to attribute value

Tags: mysql

I have following tables

post

```
id  element_id   element_type
1      1           text
2      1           image
3      1           video
```

text

```
id   message  
 1    asdfa sdf
```

image

```
 id  path  
 1    asfda/asfd/asdf
```

video

```
 id    link
 1     asdf/asdfasdf
```

I want to fetch data according to  element_type.
for example if element_type is text then it should fetch data from text table .
How to write query for this.

If element_type is text then it should not see the image and video table. It should fetch data only from text and post table.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `left join` to get all data even if  `null`

```
select p.*, t.*, i.*, v.*
from post p
left join text t on t.id = p.element_id and p.element_type = 'text'
left join image i on i.id = p.element_id and p.element_type = 'image'
left join video v on v.id = p.element_id and p.element_type = 'video'
```

Comment: I dont know. But i think for a text that is stored in text table this query also traverse image table and video table. If `element_type` is text then it should not see the image and video table. It should fetch data only from text and post table.

Comment: If your tables are properly indexed then this additional scan (because of the joins) would be v minimal.

Comment: You either do this or do two queries. I don't think there are many options.

Comment: Which one is efficient above join or two queries

Comment: Í recommend running both and see.